# Volkswagen Vento ABS sensor repair

Tags: vw, car, abs

I am using Volkswagen Vento. Its one of abs sensor damaged. Is it possible to repair the sensor. One sensor worth 4k.

During the first time the abs warning lights were disappear after pump the break pedal 10 times. Now the warning light is on.

Model : 2013

Location : India

Sensor Location : Right Back

Comment: A model year and location of the sensor would be helpful

Comment: The sensor costs about 40 only where I live.

Comment: @JimmyB: 4000 rupees = 53 euro. Little more expensive in India.

Comment: Sensor failure = switch on engine light goes off. Move and light comes back on and doors lock before approaching min speed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the sensor itself is damaged it would be a challenging task (if not impossible) to repair it.

There could be also other causes. I would suggest you to check the following things:

1. Most of times just the abs ring needs to get cleaned. The ring is on the backside of the wheel hub. Remove the brake disc, then clean the abs ring gently with a wooden spike, a fine brass brush, pressurized air and brake cleaner.
2. Perhaps the sensor connection has a bad connection. Try to clean the contacts with a fine brass brush or contact spray. Plugging it in and out several times can also restore contact.
3. It is also possible that the sensor cable is damaged, a repair of the cable should be doable. Check the entire cable (going back to the ecu).

Comment: i will try and update you soon

Comment: During the first time the abs warning lights were disappear after pump the break pedal 10 times. Now the warning light is on.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Even me too faced the same problem with front right sensor. Sensor life is good however, it can go faulty. But most of the time cleaning the ring in the hub may clear the problem. Sensor cannot repair. You can get one from Skoda Rapid since both are similar vehicle. Check the model.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!